# 'Enter key' behaviour on selected row in grid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridview` and every time when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> I am open another dialog which is fine, but when I close this short dialog, why the row selection goes to next row in the grid? I want to stop it. Please help.

Comment: Can you share your code? Presently your question is too broad.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [SuppressKeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
      // Show your dialog
      e.SuppressKeyPress = true;  // disable 'enter' key behavior.
   }
}
```